# Android display a button with OnTouchListener

Tags: android, button, android-widget, visible, ontouchlistener

I have a button that disappears 3 seconds after I press on it. I would like to make it visible again by touching the screen.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Runnable buttonRunnable;
    Handler buttonHandler = new Handler();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        buttonRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        };

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {   

                buttonHandler.postDelayed(buttonRunnable, 3000);
            }
        });
    }



private OnTouchListener buttonOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            final Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
            final LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);

            linearLayout.setClickable(true);
            linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(View view) {   

                    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            return true;
        }

    };

}
```

I am able to hide the button after 3 seconds but I cannot make it visible again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    Runnable buttonRunnable;
    Handler buttonHandler = new Handler();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
        final Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        buttonRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        };

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {   

                buttonHandler.postDelayed(buttonRunnable, 3000);
            }
        });

        linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(buttonOnTouchListener);
    }

    private OnTouchListener buttonOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            final Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a reference to the parent container view, and make sure you call setClickable(true) on it. Then, attach another click handler to that view, and in that click handler, call button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Sky Kelsey. I am very new to Android and I'm not sure how I can get a reference to the parent container view and call setClickable(true) on it. Can you please provide an example of how I can do this in my particular case?

Comment: In your layout, make sure you set an id for top level parent container view, which is most likely a LinearLayout. Then, use findViewById() to get a reference to that view.

Comment: I've updated my original code with your solution. I've put everything inside the OnTouchListener and I still can't get the button to be visible.

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood you. Do you want to make the button visible again after touching anywhere on the screen, or just where the button was when it was visible. If the latter, then you need to change the button visibility to View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE. View.GONE removed the view entirely from the layout, so it won't have a chance to receive touches. View.INVISIBLE just doesn't draw the view, but it can still get touch events. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the difference between GONE and INVISIBLE, it's good to know that. I just want the button to be visible again after touching anywhere on the screen. I have changed my View.GONE to View.INVISIBLE but I still can't get it to appear. I have very limited knowledge in Android but I think the problem is somewhere in my OnTouchListener method.